# Is there a way to get a second line of text to fill vertically?

Tags: css, html, web, alignment, push

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the various products to line up properly on my site. Some of the items have a name long enough to create a second line of text, and when it does so, the items still align with the top of the text rather than aligning the top of each image. Basically I want it to use up some of the empty space above each div to fit a second line of text, rather than pushing my picture down and just aligning at the top. This is the code I'm using to create the divs in a loop within my PHP:

```
<div class="new_prod_box">
  <a href="details.html">
    '.$title.'
  </a>
  <div class="new_prod_bg">
    <a href="details.html">
      <img src="images/'.$image.'" alt="'.$title.'" title="" class="thumb" border="0" />
    </a> 
  </div>
  <a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$id.'">
    <u>Add to cart</u>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's a picture explaining what I mean: [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRp97.jpg)

Here's the rules in my CSS:

```
.new_prod_box{
float:left;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
width:132px;
height:180px;
}
.new_prod_box a{
padding:5px 0 5px 0;
color:#b5b5b6;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;


}
.new_prod_bg{
width:132px;
height:119px;
text-align:center;
background:url(images/new_prod_box.gif) no-repeat center;
position:relative;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, if I understand your issue correctly, giving `.new_prod_box > a:first-child` (selects only the first, top-level `<a>` element inside `.new_prod_box`) a defined height should give you what you want. As long as the height is great enough to fit two lines of text in it, it'll keep the elements below in the same position, but still leaves space for the title to break to two lines.

If that isn't what you're looking for, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

(Edit:) To align single-line titles to the top of the image (rather than having whitespace between them), you could try this method, which I think will work.

First, modify your HTML structure a bit, to add a `<span>` inside of the first `<a>` element:

```
<div class="new_prod_box">
  <a href="details.html">
    <span>
      '.$title.'
    </span>
  </a>
  <div class="new_prod_bg">
    <a href="details.html">
      <img src="images/'.$image.'" alt="'.$title.'" title="" class="thumb" border="0" />
    </a> 
  </div>
  <a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$id.'">
    <u>Add to cart</u>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then, add/modify these styles in your CSS:

```
.new_prod_box > a:first-child{
   height: [tall enough for two lines];
   position:relative;
}
.new_prod_box > a:first-child span{
   display:block;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Which I believe should give you what you want. Try it out though, and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! That works excellently! Do you happen to know how I can make the titles that only take up one line to be right above the picture instead of leaving an empty line where a second line of text would normally be? It's only if you happen to know, I'm just happy my pictures line up.

Comment: Hmmm...that might require you to adjust your HTML structure a bit, since it requires absolute/relative positioning. Stand by for an updated answer.

Comment: Ok no worries, thank you again for your time. I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation apparently >.>

Comment: Haha, it's all right, as long as your question gets answered. =D

Comment: Yeah amazingly, here's a picture if you're curious :) [Picture](http://i.imgur.com/K2RDY6O.jpg?1). Thanks again!